# numpy map 2D array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, iteration

I'm trying to map values of 2D numpy array, i.e. to iterate (efficiently) over rows and append values based on row index.

One of approaches I have tried is:

```
source = misc.imread(fname) # Load some image
img = np.array(source, dtype=np.float64) / 255 # Cast and normalize values
w, h, d = tuple(img.shape) # Get dimensions
img = np.reshape(img, (w * h, d)) # Flatten 3D to 2D

# The actual problem:
# Map (R, G, B) pixels to (R, G, B, X, Y) to preserve position
img_data = ((px[0], px[1], px[2], idx % w, int(idx // w)) for idx, px in enumerate(img))
img_data = np.fromiter(img_data, dtype=tuple) # Get back to np.array
```

but the solution raises: `ValueError: cannot create object arrays from iterator`

Can anyone suggest how to perform efficiently this absurdly simple operation in `numpy`? It's out of my mind how intricate is this library... And why that code consumes a few gigs of memory for 7000x5000 px?

Thanks

Comment: why aren't you generating a list of whatever you want, and then simply convert everything to `np array` using `np.array(img_data)`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe `np.concatenate` and `np.indices`:

```
np.concatenate((np.arange(40).reshape((4,5,2)), *np.indices((4,5,1))), axis=-1)[:,:,:-1]
Out[264]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 2,  3,  0,  1],
        [ 4,  5,  0,  2],
        [ 6,  7,  0,  3],
        [ 8,  9,  0,  4]],

       [[10, 11,  1,  0],
        [12, 13,  1,  1],
        [14, 15,  1,  2],
        [16, 17,  1,  3],
        [18, 19,  1,  4]],

       [[20, 21,  2,  0],
        [22, 23,  2,  1],
        [24, 25,  2,  2],
        [26, 27,  2,  3],
        [28, 29,  2,  4]],

       [[30, 31,  3,  0],
        [32, 33,  3,  1],
        [34, 35,  3,  2],
        [36, 37,  3,  3],
        [38, 39,  3,  4]]])
```

the `[:,:,:-1]` strips an 'extra' `0` entry, maybe there's a better way